# Canvas Text update - Python3 Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter Canvas with a `C.create_text`, determined by a variable.

```
var = "Hello"
C = tk.Canvas(top, width = 1000, height = 500)
p = C.create_text(500, 80, text = var, font = "monaco")
```

and when I press a button it changes the variable, but I have no idea how to update the text in the canvas

```
def add():
    var = "Hello World"

b = tk.Button(text = "world", command = add)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
C.itemconfigure(p, text=var)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much